# Postfix: force local users (PHP) to use the SMTPD for outside recipients

Tags: postfix, sendmail, maildrop

My server has been hacked and was sending lots of spam over the Internet.
The first thing I did is shutdown postfix, close the outgoing port 25 and take the time to clean the website, the postfix queues, and to re-setup postfix completely.

I enabled lots of restrictions on the Postfix SMTPD, like forcing SASL authentification and TLS.

But I'm just thinking, PHP `mail()` function doesn't care about SMTPD, because it calls `sendmail`, whose emails end in the `maildrop` queue, and finally in the `incoming` queue (and bypass all of my SMTPD protections).

I made a small sketch of Postfix daemons and queues for myself, in order to understand better how it works.
[image: Postfix overview]

I would like following setup:

- **Prevent sendmail from delivering emails to outside recipients, but allow it to deliver emails to local users, and allow it to follow mappings in /etc/aliases even if it is an "ouside" mapping.**

My aim is that at the end, users have no other choice than contact local SMTPD directly, thus forced to login thanks to my `smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject` configuration.

Comment: Why not disable the `mail()` function?

Comment: Disable mail function is not enough.
They could use `exec("sendmail")` (yes, I could disable this too!) ; local SSH users could still use `sendmail`

I really want to prevent sendmail from sending emails over the Internet. PHP may not be the only user of sendmail on the machine. Many programs could call it.

Comment: Thanks! :-) I have to say, postfix seams so complicated at first that it was worth taking the time to read the documentation and draw up a small sketch.

Comment: If they hack you, how do you prevent them from undoing your changes? Not saying it's not a good idea, but you may want to raise some additional barriers outside the environment an attacker can gain control over.

Comment: Yes, I have already done this (like `open_basedir`, disable dangerous functions, use of suhosin, PHP-fastcgi with suexec, etc., but I still want to restrict "sendmail". Because even I'm not hacked, but there are other users on the server. It is a common practice that we "never should trust users".
For example I'd like to apply some smtpd_***_restrictions but on sendmail. I don't want a local user to send email with a strange `MAIL FROM:` address. I don't know whether restrict sendmail like smtpd is possible or not (except `authorized_submit_users`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a partial answer.

Here is how to decide which local user is allowed to use `sendmail`.

- Create a file **/etc/postfix/sendmailAllowedUsers**, put "user OK" on a line for each allowed user.
- Add `authorized_submit_users = hash:/etc/postfix/sendmailAllowedUsers` in **main.cf**
- Run `postmap /etc/postfix/sendmailAllowedUsers`
- Run `postfix reload`

This is only a partial answer to my question, because this completely removes access to **sendmail** and **mail** command for non-listed users, which is not what I wanted to do.

I wanted that every one can use `sendmail`, but only for local recipients.

Comment: Did you find any other appropriate solution? Also can your share the exact sample content of the file sendmailAllowedUsers

Comment: I think you need to use `postmap /etc/postfix/sendmailAllowedUsers` before you reload postfix to have the data available as soon as you start.

Comment: Thanks @AlexisWilke, answer edited!