# How can I force PHP to go through my local Postfix SMTP instead of going straight to the destination?

Tags: postfix, sendmail, smtp

I have a website with forms where users can send us requests. In addition, the site sends a predefined email to the client. The form receives spam (big surprise) and I'm trying to block emails from going out when some `hacker@example.com` emails are used because the destination already told us (at least once) that the email is invalid.

```
+-----------------+
| Webform         |
+------+----------+
       |
       v
+-----------------+
| PHP             |
+------+-------+--+
       |       |
       |       +-----------------+
       |                         |
       | send form data to us    | send thank you note
       v                         v
+----------------------+  +--------------------+
| contact@example.com  |  | hacker@example.com |
+----------------------+  +--------------------+
```

I'd like to at least block the email on the right (the one being sent to `hacker@example.com`).

For the purpose, I have a `bad_recipients` file with a list of regular expressions:

```
/.*hack.*@example.com/ REJECT
...
```

That works great from my computer, but from local PHP scripts, all the emails go through.

```
+---------------------------+           +---------------------------+
|                           |           |                           |
|  +---------------------+  |           |  +---------------------+  |
|  |                     |  |  SMTP     |  |                     |  |
|  | My Computer Postfix +--|-----------|->| Server Postfix      +--|---> destination
|  |                     |  |           |  |                     |  |
|  +---------------------+  |           |  +---------------------+  |
|             ^             |           |             ^             |
|             | What here?  |           |             | What here?  |
|  +----------+----------+  |           |  +----------+----------+  |
|  |                     |  |           |  |                     |  |
|  | My Computer Tool    |  |           |  | PHP Website         |  |
|  |                     |  |           |  |                     |  |
|  +---------------------+  |           |  +---------------------+  |
|                           |           |                           |
+---------------------------+           +---------------------------+
```

*Note: **What here?** — I think this is using `sendmail` and [`postdrop`](https://www.postfix.org/postdrop.1.html). Can you confirm?*

I'm thinking that the the **PHP Website** being local to the **Server Postfix** does not use **SMTP**. Instead, it would use `sendmail` and that means it bypasses the **SMTP** protections:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions=check_recipient_access regexp:/etc/postfix/bad_recipients, ...
```

Yet, PHP is clearly setup for SMTP:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

Unless that setup is ignored because I'm not under Win32 and thus those parameters would be totally ignored on Linux? (I'm on **Ubuntu**.)

Is there any way to force Postfix to check the recipient list even when sending emails via `sendmail`?

Another question in link with the potential [`sendmail`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83021/postfix-force-local-users-php-to-use-the-smtpd-for-outside-recipients) issue. But the answer is to block senders completely (from what I understand) opposed to letting emails through, but still verifying the recipient email address.

Do you have an idea on how to make sure recipients always get blocked?

Comment: When you say block recipients list (which is largely a total waste of time, similar to using IP block lists), are these contact form spams? Or are they actually using your SMTP server to send spam? It sounds to me like your email sending logic has some really big security holes in it if you are having trouble with emails getting SENT, not incoming spams to contact forms. We deal with this issue heavily and what you are describing sounds like a significant error in your email flow. More details are needed, I don't understand the actual problem source, this problem shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Lizardx Nothing's perfect, for sure... I made an update to better explain what the website does (i.e. presents a form you can fill in and that generates two emails: one to us and one preformatted to the client). So the mail server itself and the websites are working properly... except that postfix does not seem to prevent the website from sending to any recipient and that seems to be the case because it would not be using SMTP (i.e. no SMTP between the PHP process and postfix—it then uses SMTP to forward to email to the final destination).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the settings for SMTP server and port in PHP configuration are for Windows version of PHP only. Under Linux (and other Unix-like systems), PHP uses directly `/usr/sbin/sendmail` command to send mail.

As you correctly assume, the mail does not go in via SMTP but is injected directly into Postfix queue, so `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` are not applied to it.

You have basically four options:

1. block sending mail to unwanted addresses directly in your web form(s), not in the mail server
2. write (or find somewhere in the Net) a **milter** that will do the mail filtering that you need and call it via `non_smtpd_milters` setting in your Postfix config
3. In your PHP code, instead of a simple `mail()` function, use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library to send mail. PHPMailer can be configured to send mail via SMTP.
4. Replace the `/usr/sbin/sendmail` file with a **wrapper script** that will check the recipient addresses provided and remove the "bad" ones (that is a bit tricky, as the recipient addresses can be specified either on command line, or - when using `-t` parameter to `sendmail` - in the message headers), then calls the "real" sendmail binary which you have to rename to some different name. You can also leave `/usr/sbin/sendmail` as it is and use `sendmail_path` parameter in your PHP configuration which will point to your script. I think you can even install something like [msmtp](https://marlam.de/msmtp/) and set the `sendmail_path` parameter to point to it, which will effectively force your `mail()` function to send mail via SMTP.

Comment: My main problem with (4) is the password... I guess (1) is probably the best/easiest in my situation.

Comment: What password? You don't need to send mail through the submission service, where a password wold be needed. This is all within localhost, so send it normally through port 25 without any password. Postfix normally should trust localhost and relay the mail.

Comment: phpMailer is very well written and maintained, much better control, and handles complex scenarios well. These spams should be captured on the PHP side, not the email server side, that's why I was confused, you intercept it before it gets to the email server, so the email server is never in question. Then send requests once validated etc to emailer tool, and it all 'just works'. Adding the filter step to the php form processor also allows you to do much more granular spam detections. IP and email to / from lists are useless, waste of time, they automate this stuff so each time new address used.